# How can i add unlimited undo on blender?

Tags: customization

In Maya i used to have undo limit to infinite here it is restricted to 256 steps. Is there a way to increase that?

Comment: I think infinite steps are not possible (unless modifying the blender source and recompiling), atm. Unlimited memory used is possible, setting the "memory limit" to 0 (zero)

Comment: I changed the memory limit to maximum..It was 0 before. What does it change?. please explain me clearly

Comment: citing the manual (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/editing.html)>: "Steps: Number of Undo steps available., Memory Limit: Maximum memory usage in Mb (0 is unlimited)." ie: zero means "unlimited" (thus, I guess it's only limited by the system available memory)

Comment: Under user preferences-> Editing -> Global Undo -> increase steps -> from 32 default to maybe 999

Comment: @ateks that does not work! it gets reset to the real maximum (256)...

Comment: How to modify and  recompile blender source for unlimited Undo?